# Can we use different prepositions using Future Perfect Tense?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, future-perfect

My questions is: Can we use different prepositions using Future Perfect Tense?

Some context. I will have finished my work BY 10 o'clock or BEFORE 10 o'clock or UNTIL 10 o'clock.

I heard that only BY can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By** would mean you intend around 10. Also the lack of an exact conformation means you are giving an estimate.

**Before** would mean you are saying this will definitely be done by 10. The fact that you are giving a FIXED time means that this is not an estimate. Therefore both if used right are right for referring to future tense.

When you use "**until**" it is wrong because until is not correct according to the tense of the sentence. But you can use until in this for

> My work will not be finished **until** 10 o' clock

Is the correct way to frame it.